# Plot R-tree in map

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I 'am new to neo4j and newer to its spatial plugin.
Recently i was able to create an R-tree of NYC Cabs locations(*pickup* and *drop-off*) and some relationships between them (trip relationship) as well the Time Location Relationships with time nodes.

my question is : is it possible to plot this R-tree in map ?
[image]